# Why running queries one by one yields correct results, but running lots of them in one chunk doesn't?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say I create a simple table and a stored function to populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(255)
)//

CREATE FUNCTION populateIfNotAlreadyIn (idArg INT, valArg VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE alreadyIn INT;
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO alreadyIn FROM t WHERE id = idArg;
    IF alreadyIn <> 0 THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO t (id, val) VALUES (idArg, valArg);
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END//
```

Of course, the intended behaviour is that the function returns `0` if a row with the given ID already exists in the table, and `1` if it doesn't (in the latter case, the function also inserts such a row).

So now testing comes.

If I run testing queries in phpmyadmin one by one like that:

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(1, 'val1');
```

//Go//

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(2, 'val2');
```

//Go//

```
… etc
```

Then apparently, the results are correct: the function returns `1` and inserts a row if and only if there is no row with such an id in the table, otherwise it returns `0`.

So far, so good. But instead of running queries one by one, let's feed phpmyadmin with all of them at once. To be more specific, let's insert into phpmyadmin sth like this:

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(1, 'val1');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(2, 'val2');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(3, 'val3');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(4, 'val4');
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(5, 'val5');
```

And then click `Go`, to run all of them.

Result? The rows are inserted correctly into table `t`. But the stored function returns incorrect values. Each call except the last one returns a `0`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT populateIfNotAlreadyIn(1, 'val1'),
       populateIfNotAlreadyIn(2, 'val2'),
       populateIfNotAlreadyIn(3, 'val3'),
       populateIfNotAlreadyIn(4, 'val4'),
       populateIfNotAlreadyIn(5, 'val5') ;
```

Meanwhile, you could shorten the function to just

```
RETURN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = idArg);
```

Comment: Works nicely, thank you. But, could you kindly explain to me, why does your approach work, but mine not?

Comment: Most clients (eg, phpmyadmin) only perform 1 statement at a time.  Yours was 5 statements; mine was 1.